# Equation script for scaling rebirth cost not working

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically I'm making a roblox clicker game where I have rebirths which have a cost and i made a `menuOrganiser` script that basically automatically makes rebirth buttons every time the value of `players.upgrades.rebirthbuttons` changes and I have added an equation that should scale the cost every time I rebirth but for someone it doesn't change the cost on the actual screen it says that the cost is 800 but when you try to rebirth with 800 clicks it doesn't work so it changes it but not the GUI and I'm wondering why.

This is the script with the equation for the rebirths. And I also get this error:

> Players.kukata4321.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.RebirthMenu.ScrollingFrame.menuOrganiser:55: attempt to index number with 'Value'

```lua
    ...
    rebirthButtons.Changed:Connect(function()
    local amount = rebirthButtons.Value
    for count = 1, amount do
        if not scrollingframe:FindFirstChild(rebirthOptions[count]) then
            local newButton = template:Clone()
            local rebirthsAmount = rebirthOptions[count]
            newButton.Name = rebirthsAmount
            newButton.rebirthAmount.Text = rebirthsAmount.." Rebirths"
            newButton.cost.Text = rebirthsAmount*800*((1)+((rebirths.Value)/10)).. " Clicks"
            newButton.Parent = scrollingframe
        end
    end
end)

    rebirths.Changed:Connect(function()
    local rebirths = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Rebirths").Value
    for _, child in pairs(scrollingframe:GetChildren()) do
        if child:IsA("TextButton") then
            local rebirthsAmount = tonumber(child.Name)
            child.cost.Text = rebirthsAmount*800*((1)+((rebirths.Value)/10)).. " Clicks"
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what your error means is that you defined a variable with an IntValue's value (which is a number) and then tried to get the "Value" of a number

Eg:

```lua
local rebirths = game.Players.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value -- returns a number
print(rebirths.Value) -- 12345.Value doesn't work
```

The simple solution is to remove `.Value` from when you define the variable

```lua
    rebirths.Changed:Connect(function()
    local rebirths = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Rebirths") -- Remove .Value
    for _, child in pairs(scrollingframe:GetChildren()) do
        if child:IsA("TextButton") then
            local rebirthsAmount = tonumber(child.Name)
            child.cost.Text = rebirthsAmount*800*((1)+((rebirths.Value)/10)).. " Clicks"
        end
    end
```